# How to change size of font inside text property

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

```
<s:Label fontSize="24" text="{myVar}с" width="100%" textAlign="center"/>
```

is possible to change the letter `c` near with {myVar}, if the main size of the label is 24, i want this letter to be 14, how to do this?

Comment: maybe you can use two labels on top of each other

Comment: Try using a `RichText` component to do this, or do what @RST suggested. I just answered another question of yours and gave some info that should hopefully make it obvious how to do this with a `RichText` object.